# What is column syntax for odata linked table

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a normal WCF service where there is a product that belongs to a department.

The URL to get a department of a given product would look like this:

```
http://localhost:49168/RapDataService.svc/Products(1000)/Department/Name
```

Using Razor I can have the foreignkey column that does what I want, but I can't find the syntax for JavaScript. I would assume something like this:

```
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Department#Name",
                    filterable: false
                },
```

But I can't find the correct syntax anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer, just have to expand the datasource

```
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost:49168/RapDataService.svc/Products",
                        data: { $expand: "Department"}
                    }
                },
```

And then the syntax I was looking for was the dot.

```
                {
                    field: "Department.Name",
                    title: "Afdeling",
                    filterable: true
                },
```